# All Disqus comments must be approved first

Tags: disqus

Is it possible that all comments on my site must be approved before they are shown?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screening comments is only available in "Disqus Classic", not Disquis 2012, as noted in this [help article](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466238-moderating-your-community). There is more information on Disquis 2012 and how to turn it on and off at [this FAQ](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-disqus-2012-and-f-a-q-).

To enable screening, the instructions in the first link suggest:

> Screening options can be found at the Disqus admin > Settings >
>   Moderators page. You can choose to pre-screen either all comments or
>   comments made by guest profiles. You may also choose to screen
>   comments which contain links as a way to control spammers and against
>   posting inappropriate links.

Comment: Ok it's only available in "Disqus Classic".

Comment: @Bendim You misunderstood. It is also available in Disqus 2012, just the setting's pane does not exist yet. So to activate it, you must disable disqus 2012, than choose the options you want, and reactivate disqus 2012, your options will carry over.